# Unix Shell Script Logic

Tags: unix

My Primary Job role is not scripting, however I need to build a script for my Project need as one time. Pls advise some expertise !!..

Here is my ask.
a. A script that can read all files in a directory. 
b. Each file has values like below 
ABC*I*2679956.33
Xx
xx
xx
PCB*4304096*20181231*AH*0*AH>444*215341.25

The number of rows may be different, but I wanted to print "2679956.33" ( right after ABC*I* - This is constant)
and 215341.25 ( right after AH>444*) as an email ...

Could you pls advise. Thanks

Comment: we are here to help you with coding issues, not to code the script for you, but i can tell you this is pretty easy, 1 line of code.

Answer (score 1):

i shouldn't.. but..

```
awk -F "*" '{ print $3, $9 }' /yourfolder/* | awk '{ print $1, $6 }' | mailx -r sender@mail.com -s "subject" recipient@mail.com
```

Comment: Thank you.. I didn't realize it.. I was also building the script which I had issues.. i will try this if any additional questions, I will revert back.. thank you!!

Comment: np, mark the question as answered if you are happy with it, and good luck